# PayPal Express shipping cost does not update on patch

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I patch the order **Total** is right, but **Shipping** is still holding old shipping price (**4.50**)

For example i've try to patch it with 24.60

[image]

This is my code for [onShippingChange](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/shipping-callback/)

```
onShippingChange: function (data, actions) {                    
    data.action = "changeShippingCost";
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + '/paypalExpress/request',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    }).then(function (res) {
        if (res.accept) {
            shippingAmount = (res.shipping);
            baseOrderAmount = (res.value);
            itemsTotal = (res.itemsTotal);
            return actions.order.patch([
                {
                    op: 'replace',
                    path: '/purchase_units/@reference_id==\'default\'/amount',
                    value: {
                        currency_code: 'EUR',
                        value: (parseFloat(baseOrderAmount)).toFixed(2),
                        breakdown: {
                            item_total: {
                                currency_code: 'EUR',
                                value: (parseFloat(itemsTotal)).toFixed(2)
                            },
                            shipping: {
                                currency_code: 'EUR',
                                value: (parseFloat(shippingAmount)).toFixed(2)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
        }
        return actions.reject();
    });
},
```

I've managed to create a minimal reproducible example without the server side [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ytpz194/)

UPDATE:
After contacting [PayPal Suport](https://www.paypal-support.com/) they send me

> Thank you for contacting Merchant Technical Support.
>
> Based on the information provided in the ticket, it is my
> understanding that you are inquiring about patching the shipping costs
> into your smart payment buttons. I worked with some of my peers on
> this and I have included the suggested code for what you are looking
> to accomplish here

and [this attachment](https://jsfiddle.net/3m2xadhz/)

So I need to change the **tax_total** to change a **shipping** or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the [minimal reproducible example](https://jsfiddle.net/5ytpz194/) without the server side, shipping was immediately changed to 24.60 ...

[image]

Therefore the issue would appear to be with the server side (perhaps it is still returning 4.50?).  You should console.log() the `res.shipping` and debug from there

Comment: Thx for you answer, No on the server side is returning 24.60, `shippingChageData` is a copy of what is coming from the server side. Maybe that is happening only in sandbox, or some settings in my sandbox account?

Comment: It's happening even on live env. In one case it event does not update the total price. But the order was successfully patched

Comment: Testing again I was able to reproduce, and saw the patch being sent correctly in the Network tab. Looks like a PayPal issue, possibly depending on which version of a subsystem handles a request. You can report it as a bug using your minimum reproducible example

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and efforts. It's reported.